# Why is a join Cint(char field) on int field faster than int to int?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, query-optimization

I am running the following 2 queries in microsoft access that yield the same result, but the second query runs in about 5 seconds whereas the first one takes about 10 minutes. I am completely lost here. The first query joins an integer field on another integer field and the second query joins a `cint(text)` field onto an integer field and runs MUCH faster.

Runs in 10 minutes:

I set tblA.number = integer field

```
SELECT A, B, sum(d) as C
FROM tblA 
INNER JOIN (tblB INNER JOIN tblC ON tblB.A = tblC.A) 
    ON tblA.number = tbl B.B)
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING F like '*808*'
```

Runs in 5 seconds: - notice the `cint(tblA.A)`

```
I set tblA.number = text field
SELECT A, B, sum(d) as C
FROM tblA 
INNER JOIN (tblB INNER JOIN tblC ON tblB.A = tblC.A) 
    ON cint(tblA.number) =   tbl B.B)
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING F like '*808*'
```

Comment: If you repeat the test, do you get similar results (ie no 1-time optimization costs)?  What is the definition of `tblB`?

Comment: are you sure that in your first query your tblA.number is a number?

Comment: `HAVING A like '*808*'`: is column A in this clause the same field that you are changing back and forth from a number to text?

Comment: sorry I realized my error and changed - I changed the field names in order to make it more reader-friendly, but I realize I may have just added confusion.

Comment: Try googling JETSHOWPLAN.  That will let you look into the Jet query plan for each query.  That will likely give you your answer.  If you can't make sense of the showplan.out file it produces, you can post that as part of your question and we can interpret it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying tblA.number is a char data type?

I think it makes sense that using cint() would be faster since you convert the string to a number and THEN do a number comparison to the tblB.B column.

I cannot imagine anyone being surprised that comparing strings (which occurs character by character) will run anything close to comparing two numbers.

In the first example since the data types do not match, then the first tblA.number is a string, and thus it likely converts the tblB.B column into a string for that comparison.

So converting a number to a string is likely slower (more memory needs to be allocated for the string space, and then there is the issue of garbage collection when you toss out the string).  So not only creating the string going to cost time but worse doing a string comparison is going to be slower.

With cint() you convert (cast) the string to a number (probably faster then to string) and then you are doing a number comparison (which is most certainly faster then a string compare).

So I cannot say for certain the above is the reason, but it certainly would not a be surprise. As noted, using ShowPlan could perahps yield some more information here.

Comment: No showplan in access, but I suspect your answer is correct. If you are comparing fields of two types making the conversion explict may change the order of operations to enable the use of an index which couldn't be used otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

this is not normal situation... unless there are indexes only for text field.

Comment: there were no indexes on either of them; however, I indexed the integer field and it runs about as fast as the text field. however, with no indexes I have no idea why the cint is faster

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities that come to mind:

- maybe the text field or expression in the second query causes the query optimizer to pick a different and more appropriate join strategy.
- maybe the query optimizer is somehow able to detect that all your numbers are very small in the second case leading it to use a smaller data type than int resulting in faster reads.
- maybe having the text field there causes the data to align differently in the pages causing  better read and cache performance.
- maybe there was some background activity which affected your test machine in a very negative way during one test

Unfortunately, there are a lot of factors in query planning and optimization.  Sometimes it's just not possible to understand why stuff happens the way it does.